Debian 12 doesn't detect touchpad on ThinkPad X1 (Gen 12)
Debian Bookworm doesn't detect touchpad on ThinkPad X1 Gen 12:

No touchpad menu in System > Control Center > Mouse,

xinput list mentions TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint but not touchpad.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜ ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                   id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                      id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
  ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard              id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Video Bus                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Power Button                             id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Sleep Button                             id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ sof-hda-dsp Headphone                    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Intel HID events                         id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard             id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                   id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]



Where do I start?
Touchpad detected by Ubuntu 24.04.1 (live boot) with a more recent kernel (Linux 6.8). Solve for Debian with a kernel upgrade:
sudo apt install linux-image-6.10.6+bpo-amd64

Use apt search linux-image to find the latest kernel. Or, more simply, apt search linux-image-amd64 which outputs something like linux-image-amd64/stable-backports,now 6.10.6-1~bpo12+1 amd64 [installed].

Please [edit] your question and show us the full output of xinput list.

@terdon Done, thanks.

OK, that's odd. Are you 100% sure the touchpad is working? Is this a new machine? Did it ever work on a different OS? Can you boot into another OS (either an installed, dual boot system or a live CD from any Linux) and see if it works there?

Touchpad is enabled in BIOS. I've never gotten it working in Debian. X1 Gen 12 is new. I wondered whether the hardware is too new. I could try live-booting Ubuntu.

Looking through https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Thinkpad/ I don't see one about a 12th gen X1, but all the rest seem to be fine. I am leaning towards the cop out of suggesting a hardware issue...

Works fine on Ubuntu 24.04.1, xinput list includes the touchpad

Oh. Huh. OK, please add that to the question (comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning) so the next person to read this can see it.
